# Visual Studio Code remote: Invalid username or password fatal: Authentication failed

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio code editor issue is it is not asking for password when i run
`git push origin branchname`

```
remote: Invalid username or password
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://bitbucket.org/..../.....git/'
```

but it was working properly before.

I tried these commands also

```
git config --unset user.password

git config credential.helper ""
```

now when i try to push code it is giving me following errors :

```
fatal: credential-cache unavailable; no unix socket support
remote: Invalid username or password
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://bitbucket.org/..../.....git/'
```

but from command prompt i'm able to push code. Is there any way i can enable password dialog to appear when i push the code.
Thanks

Comment: `user.password` is meaningless: you might as well `git config --unset aardvark.purple`. Nothing cares about it, nobody uses it, so don't set or unset it. The `credential.helper`, on the other hand, does matter, but you'll need a VSCode expert to tell you what it *should* be set to here.

Comment: What is your OS and Git version? What does `git config --global credential.helper` return?

Comment: @VonC: I'm working on windows 10, git config --global credential.helper returns `cache`, `git version 2.32.0.windows.2`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have generated a [BitBucket HTTP access token first](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/personal-access-tokens-939515499.html).
And use that as password.

I would try, from command-line:

```sh
git config --global credential.helper manager-core

git ls-remote https://bitbucket.org/..../.....git
# enter your bitbucket username/token
# check it does return the remote branch names

# Then, again:
git ls-remote https://bitbucket.org/..../.....git
# check it does return the remote branch names /without/ asking for your credentials
```

Once the `git ls-remote` is working (meaning it does no longer ask for your credentials, which are now successfully cached), close and restart VSCode.
See if the issue persists then.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set app password for bitbucket, you are trying to use account password as app password which is wrong as per bitbucket April update.

**Go to bitbucket -> personal setting page -> app password -> create a app password**

Now use this app password to push and pull the code from bitbucket !